# how can i get the id of image and move toward the related page of that id in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a rotated carousel when I click on pause button it stop  now I want that when I stop it the front image id get and move toward the related page of that id  please help me  here is the code below:

```
enter code here
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/P5295/8/

Answer (score 0):

Any solution would involve listening to the animation events. A review of this can be found here: http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-animation-javascript-event-handlers/.

You're executing only one animation for a complete 360-degree rotation using keyframes.
Unfortunately, Javascript does not provide an event for each keyframe. For example, this would only alert "hello world" when your **1** makes it all the way around:

```
$('#carousel').on('webkitAnimationIteration animationiteration', function(){
    alert('hello world')
});
```

A library to provide keyframe event functionality can be found here: http://www.joelambert.co.uk/cssa/, though they caveat that it won't work in webkit-mobile, and I don't have any experience with this myself.

If you could capture an event for each partial rotation, then to differentiate between the position of each figure in your carousel, you would probably best change state on each item through use of data-attributes. For example, you could start off with markup like this:

```
<div id="carousel">
    <figure data-on-top='true'>1</figure>
    <figure data-on-top='false'>2</figure>
    <figure data-on-top='false'>3</figure>
    <figure data-on-top='false'>4</figure>
    <figure data-on-top='false'>5</figure>
    <figure data-on-top='false'>6</figure>
    <figure data-on-top='false'>7</figure>
    <figure data-on-top='false'>8</figure>
    <figure data-on-top='false'>9</figure>
</div>
```

...then on each keyframe, change the *on-top* figure to be the next one. Then, on click, you can grab the id of the one "on-top" and do what you need to do.